# ASP.NET MVC 3 bin folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Lets say I have an MVC project called Test123. When I publish it from VS in the bin folder I have all referensed non-global(?) DLLs and Test123.dll. What is the purpose of this last file? Can I safely delete it? I thought ASP.NET will compile the site on 1st access.

Comment: Thanks spender, just haven't noticed this feature ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. In Asp.net MVC only the views are compiled on 1st access. The models and controllers will be precompiled into a DLL. Remove it, and your project will not run.